# Xamarin.Android how to seperate words from a list item

Tags: list, split, xamarin.android

I am developing an app which in which I am storing barcodes and names in a single list item.

For example, one list item may be:

"501377267837 Apples"

What I want to do is first of all check if the barcode that has been scanned already exists in the list and if it does I want to seperate the barcode from the name.

For example:

501377267837

Chicken

I was going to use String.Split but how can I then insert these seperate strings into different textviews?

Also, will the Contains() method identify the barcode even though the item contains more than just that barcode?

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list of model instead string .

The model has two properties called `Barcode` and `Name` .

You could retrieve the list and find out the item whose Barcode is identical .

```
public class Item
{
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 

List<Item> list = xx;

foreach(Item item in list)
{
     if(item.Barcode is "Specific barcode")
     {
          //handle your logic
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry I have just seen this, I am going to give this a go tonight and will update you after